# Laravel 5 setup in sqlsrv on Linux platform?

Tags: sql-server, linux, laravel-5, amazon-rds

I have MS-SQL Database for the Laravel5 which is in Linux platform(AWS-RDS).Laravel5 supports sqlsrv driver but sqlsrv doesn't get supported on Linux platforms.

I have tried FreeTDS driver and database connection is not happening.
What should I do now?